# Spring @PostContruct not waiting for complete bean creation

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

While setting up a service to have an initialization method using `@PostConstruct`, I'm calling a service that has been autowired. The method I am calling from that service in turn uses a service method that has been autowired into it, but when that service is called, I get an NPE. Indeed, all autowired fields in the second service are `null`. Having the original autowired service extend `ApplicationContextAware` proved that this service had not been fully initialized (or at least had not been made context aware).

It seems that the `@PostConstruct` is being called after my service has been made context aware, but it's not waiting until the rest of the application is context aware. How can I either have it wait on all its dependencies or change the initialization so it's called at a later point in Spring's initialization path?

Example:

```
@Service 
public class ServiceA {

  @Autowired 
  private ServiceB serviceB;

  @PostConstruct 
  public void init() {
    serviceB.someMethod();
  }
}

@Service 
public class ServiceB implements ApplicationContextAware {

  @Autowired 
  private ServiceC serviceC; // This is null at the time of   
  private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
    this.applicationContext = applicationContext; // This never gets called
  }

  @PostConstruct
  public void someMethod() {
    serviceB.someOtherMethod(); // NullPointerException
  }
}
```

Comment: you must be doing something wrong.. I've run the exact code you have and all looks good. by the time the code stops in the PostConstruct of ServiceA, ServiceB is initialized fully (applicationContext injected too) along with the serviceC injected and initialized.. Could it be that you have 2 application contexts (webapp maybe?) ?

Comment: I do have two application contexts, but the component-scan is only set up to pick up the services in to the root context (while only controllers are picked up in the web context).